# How to speed up read method call of object returned by urllib2.urlopen

Tags: python, urllib2

I have following code.

```
 req = urllib2.Request(url,'',txheaders)
 f = urllib2.urlopen(req)
 data = f.read()
 f.close()
```

In the above code, the read function takes 1-2 minutes when response is of 58KB. How can I make this faster.

Comment: @user283405, url is in your server? or any web page like that?

Comment: sometimes when `Content-Length:` value from http response is bigger than actual size, its keep waiting until timeout. but it shouldn't happen on properly configured web servers.

Comment: What platform and which version of Python are you using? I seem to remember there was a bug resulting in poor performance reading from sockets a couple of years ago so maybe you just need to try a different version of Python.

Comment: I am using python 2.6 on Windows Platform(Windows XP).